# Add "next" button to display next table entity

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, save

Still completely new to this whole xcode thing so bear with me..
Im using xcode 4's 'master-detail' template with core data. When you click a cell in the table of the rootView, it segues to a detail view passing selectedItem as managedobject "detailItem".

I want to add a "next" Button (or a swipegesture preferably, if possible) that will display the next cell/detailItem, from the table in rootView, in the detailView
(exactly like the notes.app)

Do i need to recreate a fetchedresults controller and pass the objectIndex then fetch index+1 And display that as next object?
Or is there an easier more efficient way that wont drive me crazy trying to fabricate???

any help would be Most appreciated. And hopefully detailed as i would barely understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a [delegate relationship](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) between the master and detail view controllers.  If you don't know how delegates work, check documentation in that link, and plenty of good tutorials are a Google search away… [this one's not bad](http://www.hardcodedstudios.com/home/ryan-newsome/simpledelegatetutorialforiosdevelopment).  Here's the high-level approach:

On the detail controller, you'll create an `(id) delegate` property, and a "DetailViewControllerDelegate" protocol with methods like `-(BOOL)detailViewShouldShowNextItem:(DetailViewController *)detailViewController` and a similar one for previous.

On the master controller, declare support for the protocol in the header, and then implement the delegate methods so that they select the previous or next item in the list, loading it in the detail view.

Finally, after the detail view controller is instantiated, set its delegate to be the master view controller.